# Morphisms of a Simplex Category of a simplicial set.

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

In the **Page 7** of the  book **Simplicial Homotopy theory** by *Jardine and Goerss* they defined the *simplex category  of a simplicial set $X$* as the slice category $\Delta \downarrow X$. So objects of $\Delta \downarrow X$  are simplicial maps $\sigma: \Delta^n \rightarrow 
X$ or simplices of $X$ *(by strong version of Yoneda Lemma)* and  morphisms are commutative diagrams of simplicial maps of the following form:

[image]

Then they said that the simplicial map $\theta$ is induced by a unique ordinal number map $\theta_{*}: [m] \rightarrow [n]$ where $[m], [n]$ are objects of the finite ordinal category, $\Delta$.

**I am not able to guess a natural choice of such unique ordinal map $\theta_*:[m] \rightarrow [n]$ which will induce the simplicial map $\theta: \Delta^n \rightarrow \Delta^m$**.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You mention the Yoneda lemma. Use it. The simplicial sets $\Delta^n$ are representable functors.

Comment: @ZhenLin Thank you Sir. I am trying.

Comment: What is the definition of $\Delta^n$?

Comment: @NoelLundström $\Delta^n = Hom(-,[n])$

Comment: Right, so apply the contravariant Yoneda lemma.

Comment: @NoelLundström Thank you Sir. I am trying

Comment: Right, but do you understand the argument?

Comment: @NoelLundström Applying contravariant Yoneda lemma I am getting a bijection between $Hom(\Delta^n, \Delta^m)$ and $Hom([n],[m])$. But according to my question I need a bijection between  $Hom(\Delta^n, \Delta^m)$ and $Hom([m],[n])$. Am I mistaking anything?

Comment: @NoelLundström Thank you Sir. I checked here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoneda_lemma#Contravariant_version. But according to it I should get a bijection between $Nat(\Delta^n , \Delta^m)$ and $\Delta^m([n])=Hom([n],[m])$. Am I mistaking anything?

Comment: Ah yes of course, my bad. There must be a mistake in the text you are reading or you copied the text wrong.  What you are saying here in the comments is true.

Comment: @NoelLundström Thank you Sir.